# Storing odbc connections centrally

Tags: r, rodbc

We have several databases that we access, and different scripts require one or more of these odbcconnections.  I wanted to know if instead of putting an odbcConnect line in every script if there was a method to store all the connections centrally and import them as needed?  That way if the database info changes I can update one file instead of every script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `options` in your `.Rprofile` file to save the connections. In your scripts, you would then use `getOption`.

There is also a `Rprofile.site` file which might be a better choice if you are working in a team with several R installations.

See [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html) or the R installation and administration handbook for more information.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a package with each connection as a function.